# Python - get string between parantheses

Tags: python, string, substitution

Example (suppose this is a string):

```
0.1+0.5*(sign(t-0.5)+1)*t + sign(t+0.8)
```

I have to get the string 't-0.5' and 't+0.8' between the parantheses of the sign functions (=string in this case), so that after substitution I can get for example:

```
0.1+0.5*(copysign(1,t-0.5)+1)*t + copysign(1,t+0.8)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer depends a lot on how much the text you're modifying will vary.  Is it always involving the sign() function in the way you've shown? Please provide a few examples that demonstrate how different your inputs could be.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but if you want a solution for this specific case, then here it is:

```
>>> s = '0.1+0.5*(sign(t-0.5)+1)*t + sign(t+0.8)'
>>> s.replace('sign(', 'copysign(1,')
'0.1+0.5*(copysign(1,t-0.5)+1)*t + copysign(1,t+0.8)'
```

If you want a more general replacement, it could be quite tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '0.1+0.5*(sign(t-0.5)+1)*t + sign(t+0.8)'
>>> print re.sub(r'sign\((t.*?)\)', r'copysign(1,\1)', s)
0.1+0.5*(copysign(1,t-0.5)+1)*t + copysign(1,t+0.8)
```

Someone could probably come up with a better expression; I'm not that great at regex. But it works :).

Comment: Regex will also work only in certain cases. they can't parse parenthesis (as you probably know)

Comment: @Elazar Yea, kinda figured that out as I was answering the question :p

Comment: @Elazar, regex can parse parenthesis, you just have to escape them using a backslash.

Comment: Oops, I just realised I gave my wrong print line. It should work now

Comment: @johnthexiii I believe you know very well what I meant. If this was not a joke, please explain.

Comment: @Elazar your comment does say `Regex will also work only in certain cases. they can't parse parenthesis`. I simply assumed you didn't know, I didn't mean any offense.

Comment: @johnthexiii I meant "you can't parse arbitrary [balanced strings of parentheses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language#Properties) using a regular expression, or [any model with finite memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_automaton)"